# my installed packages got lost in node_modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm

In my project i'm using `git` and `node_modules` folder is obviously ignored. i  was working `branch1` and added some dependencies(e.g `redux`) and installed them via `npm install`. then i switched to `branch2` which was created same time with `branch1` and now it has some different dependencies than `branch1`. i used `npm install` again inorder to install those packages.

so here is what happened: when i came back to `branch1` none of my already installed packages during working in `branch1` were found. i expected that 'cause `node_modules` is ignored both of branches packages exist. i had to run npm install again although i installed them before.

so my question is what caused this? is it git doing sth? or npm does sth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s a hypothetical scenario that may help explain:

1. On branch 1 you install “A”. It gets saved to `node_modules` and you commit changes to the `package.json` and `package-lock.json`.
2. You checkout branch 2, causing your `package.json` and `package-lock.json` to no longer have “A” - although your `node_modules` are left untouched (gitignored), meaning “A” is still there.
3. You run `npm install` on branch 2, which uses your `package.json` and `package-lock.json` to update your `node_modules` per their specifications. Because they don’t have “A”, it gets removed from your `node_modules`.
4. You checkout branch 1, and again your `node_modules` are unaffected by this git checkout - this means you’ll need to run “npm install” again to get “A” back in `node_modules`.

Comment: hey thanks! i thought about step 3 in my mind but i wasn't sure about that. are you sure npm removes pakcages already installed but not listed in package.json in next `npm install`?

Comment: Yes. The package.json specifies exactly what should be in node_modules. This is what allows other developers/machines (your code runs on) to run the same as you see it on your computer.